# Cross-Browser CSS3 Keyframe Animation Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, animation, css-transforms, css-animations

I have a simple "pulsating" effect on the play-button (which is an anchor tag), using CSS3 and keyframes.

While it works flawlessly in Chrome and Safari, it doesn't seem to be working in Firefox. Does anyone have an idea on why?

```
li > a {

    -webkit-animation: pulsate 3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation: pulsate 3s ease-in-out;
    -o-animation: pulsate 3s ease-in-out;
    animation: pulsate 3s ease-in-out;

    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulsate {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.8, 0.8);
        -moz-transform: scale(0.8, 0.8);
        -o-transform: scale(0.8, 0.8);
        transform: scale(0.8, 0.8);
        opacity: 0.3;
    }

    50% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
        -moz-transform: scale(1, 1);
        -o-transform: scale(1, 1);
        transform: scale(1, 1);
        opacity: 1.0;
    }

    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.8, 0.8);
        -moz-transform: scale(0.8, 0.8);
        -o-transform: scale(0.8, 0.8);
        transform: scale(0.8, 0.8);
        opacity: 0.3;
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: To ease maintainability, I recommend to use a CSS preprocessor such as [Autoprefixer](https://github.com/ai/autoprefixer).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to include the browser-specific keyframe animations with their browser-specific transforms within them

```
@-webkit-keyframes pulsate {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.8, 0.8);
        opacity: 0.3;
    }    
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
        opacity: 1.0;
    }    
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.8, 0.8);
        opacity: 0.3;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes pulsate {
    0% {
        transform: scale(0.8, 0.8);
        opacity: 0.3;
    }    
    50% {
        transform: scale(1, 1);
        opacity: 1.0;
    }    
    100% {
        transform: scale(0.8, 0.8);
        opacity: 0.3;
    }
}
@-ms-keyframes pulsate {
    0% {
        -ms-transform: scale(0.8, 0.8);
        opacity: 0.3;
    }    
    50% 
        -ms-transform: scale(1, 1);
        opacity: 1.0;
    }    
    100% {
        -ms-transform: scale(0.8, 0.8);
        opacity: 0.3;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes pulsate {
    0% {
        transform: scale(0.8, 0.8);
        opacity: 0.3;
    }    
    50% 
        transform: scale(1, 1);
        opacity: 1.0;
    }    
    100% {
        transform: scale(0.8, 0.8);
        opacity: 0.3;
    }
}
@keyframes pulsate {
    0% {
        transform: scale(0.8, 0.8);
        opacity: 0.3;
    }    
    50% {
        transform: scale(1, 1);
        opacity: 1.0;
    }    
    100% {
        transform: scale(0.8, 0.8);
        opacity: 0.3;
    }
}
```

[image: jsFiddle]

Also, you should add the `-ms-animation` equivalents to get full browser support.

---

These days, a lot of these can be left out safely. Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25110511/2065702) to find out which ones you need to include to support your target browsers.

Comment: [Related answer on prefixes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25110510/why-doesnt-css-feature-work-in-browser-but-works-in-others)

Comment: Mother of CSS3! why do browser developers have to do this to us?

Comment: @Felype It's not wholly their fault, part is due to how specs are made. But most of these can be left out these days. Check the post linked in my edit to see which you need